# How can I knit coeftest() regression outputs?

Tags: r

I first created a probit model like so:

```
fit1 <-  glm(Y ~ X1, data = dat1, family = binomial (link="probit"))
```

and used huxtable to knit the probit model results into a word doc like so

```
hux1 <- huxreg(fit1)
knitr::knit_print(hux1)
```

However, I wanted to cluster the standard errors according to commune, which I only achieved using the lmtest and sandwich packages as follows

```
sandwich1 <- coeftest(fit1, vcov. = vcovCL(fit1, cluster = dat1$commune, type = "HC0"))
```

But now I don't know how to knit this, since objects of class "coeftest" cannot be used for the approach I took for knitting the results of the fit1 object.
Also, I used the performance package to get McFadden's R2, like so

```
r2_mcfadden(fit1)
```

But this doesn't work with a coeftest object either...
How do I go knitting and obtaining the R2 of sandwich1, with clustered standard errors?

Comment: It is hard to tell without data. You should provide a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With recent versions of `lmtest` and `broom` the `huxreg()` function should be able to deal with `coeftest` objects. Moreover, setting `coeftest(..., save = TRUE)` will provide additional details in the `glance()` method and thus the `huxtable()`. Example:

```
library("huxtable") ## 5.1.1
library("lmtest")   ## 0.9-38
library("sandwich") ## 3.0-0
data("PetersenCL", package = "sandwich")
dat1 <- transform(PetersenCL,
  ybin = factor(y > 0)
)
fit1 <- glm(ybin ~ x, data = dat1, family = binomial(link = "probit"))
sandwich1 <- coeftest(fit1, vcov = vcovCL, cluster = ~ firm, type = "HC0", save = TRUE)
##                ─────────────────────────────────────────────────
##                                                            (1)  
##                                        ─────────────────────────
##                  (Intercept)                         0.022      
##                                                     (0.037)     
##                  x                                   0.497 ***  
##                                                     (0.031)     
##                                        ─────────────────────────
##                  N                                5000          
##                  logLik                          -3132.824      
##                  AIC                              6269.648      
##                ─────────────────────────────────────────────────
##                  *** p < 0.001; ** p < 0.01; * p < 0.05.        
## 
## Column names: names, model1
```

The `huxreg()` does not display the `"r.squared"` statistic but this is the same for `huxreg(fit1)` and not just `huxreg(sandwich1)`.

Also, the McFadden pseudo R-squared is likelihood-based and not adjusted along with the standard errors. (Whether it is particularly useful to report the McFadden R-squared here is a different question...but it is not unusual to see this being done.)

Comment: NB the `statistics` argument to `huxreg()` varies the statistics displayed. Anything returned from `glance()` is available.